# Multiple collapse bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my issue, I would like to get a closed collapse on each project (h3) I know the first one has to be open, but I would like all the others to be closed. Actually, the collapse is working, but they are all "open"
I tried to minimize the code to let you see the most relevant so as you can see there is only 2 project but I can have more than a hundred I removed the php because he build what you can see there.

```
<div class="categorie">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse-csnm" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="livraison_1_0 ">
                <h3>CSNM</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="well well-white test collapse-csnm in"  id="livraison_1_0"              
            <div class="well-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <blockquote class="recap">
                        <p class="labels">
                            <span class="label label-primary">Développement</span>
                            <a href=# target="_blank"><span class="label label-default">Url</span></a>
                            <span id="state-projetcheklist-1" class="state state-nosmile"></span>
                        </p>
                        <p data-toggle="collapse" href="#site-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="site">
                                Content
                        </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="categorie">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse-salt-travel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="livraison_3_0 ">
                <h3>Salt Travel</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="well well-white test collapse-salt-travel in"  id="livraison_3_0"                    <div class="well-content">
            <div class="row">
                <blockquote class="recap">
                    <p class="labels">
                        <span class="label label-primary">Intégration</span>
                        <a href=# target="_blank"><span class="label label-default">Url</span></a>
                        <span id="state-projetcheklist-3" class="state state-nosmile"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p data-toggle="collapse" href="#structure-accueil-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="structure-accueil">
                                Content
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So do you know what to do to get the first one opened and all others closed ?
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your HTML replace all `in` class with `collapse` at div who has class `well`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="categorie">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse-csnm" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="livraison_1_0 ">
                <h3>CSNM</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="well well-white test collapse-csnm collapse"  id="livraison_1_0"              
            <div class="well-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <blockquote class="recap">
                        <p class="labels">
                            <span class="label label-primary">Développement</span>
                            <a href=# target="_blank"><span class="label label-default">Url</span></a>
                            <span id="state-projetcheklist-1" class="state state-nosmile"></span>
                        </p>
                        <p data-toggle="collapse" href="#site-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="site">
                                Content
                        </p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="categorie">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse-salt-travel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="livraison_3_0 ">
                <h3>Salt Travel</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        <div class="well well-white test collapse-salt-travel collapse"  id="livraison_3_0"                    <div class="well-content">
            <div class="row">
                <blockquote class="recap">
                    <p class="labels">
                        <span class="label label-primary">Intégration</span>
                        <a href=# target="_blank"><span class="label label-default">Url</span></a>
                        <span id="state-projetcheklist-3" class="state state-nosmile"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p data-toggle="collapse" href="#structure-accueil-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="structure-accueil">
                                Content
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, this is working, now I have all collapse closed. I thought the first one had to be opened, looks like there is no need. Thousand thanks.

Comment: If you want first to be open then you can add 'in' class to first `collapse `